# how to find the markers in the individual clusters in a  marker cluster object in google maps api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I followed the tutorial here to add an inforwindow to the individual clusters of markercluster at any zoom level.
http://krisarnold.com/2010/10/15/adding-info-windows-to-map-clusters-with-google-maps-api-v3/

I want to add the info of the markers (e.g. their 'title' s to a list displayed in the info window when clicked on the markercluster object.) contained in respective cluster.

So if I have 3 clusters at a particular zoom level in view, each having 5 markers  insider it.
How do I display a list of the titles of the 5 (out of total 15 markers in markercluster object) markers aggregated in that particular cluster?

for e.g. I have 3 markers inside a cluster
then how do I show this in the info window?
titlemarker1
titlemarker2
titlemarker3

**edit**:
as seen here
http://www.blogwave.de/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/marker_cluster.png
all the different clusters are an instance of one markercluster object. So if we use the getmarkers routine of markercluster object as mentioned in one of the answers below then we get list of all markers.

What I want is for e.g. to get a list of only those 18 markers from the total markers in the cluster marked with 18, first from left.

Comment: How do you create your MarkerClusterer? Can you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, the MarkerClusterer reference is a bit scant. After browsing through [the source code](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js), it looks like you need to call the `getMarkers` method of the `cluster` object passed in (contrary to what I had previously suggested, which was to call the method on the `markerClusterer`).

For example, using the tutorial you've linked to:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
    var content = '';

    // Convert lat/long from cluster object to a usable MVCObject
    var info = new google.maps.MVCObject;
    info.set('position', cluster.center_);

    //----
    //Get markers
    var markers = cluster.getMarkers();

    var titles = "";
    //Get all the titles
    for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        titles += markers[i].getTitle() + "\n";
    }
    //----


    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.close();
    infowindow.setContent(titles); //set infowindow content to titles
    infowindow.open(map, info);

});
```

**EDIT:** Updated in response to question edit.

Comment: thanks a lot. Maybe we can suggest suitable title for my question, so that others can find it easily.

Comment: Also, how did you find out that the cluster object is available for use?

Comment: In the source code, I found out where the `clusterclick` event is declared, and what it passes. Then, I had to trace back where the `cluster` argument was originally declared to find out what type it was. Once I knew what type it was, I knew which methods were available to it.

Comment: There's also this (not immediately obvious) [reference page](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html)