# is there a way to tell which markers are being clustered using vue2-google-maps and marker-clusterer-plus

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vue2-google-maps

Hello Everyone I would like to find out if there is a way to tell what custom markers are being clustered and also if there is a way to listen to the change of the markers being declustered on zoom in?

```
<template>
<gmap-map
  ref="gmap"
  :options="{
    disableDefaultUi: true,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    rotateControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    clickableIcons: false
  }"
  :center="center.hasOwnProperty('lat') ? center : markers[0].position"
  :zoom="10"
  :style="{ width: width, height: height }"
>
   <gmap-cluster
      :gridSize="30"
      :zoomOnClick="true"
      :enableRetinaIcons="true"
      :minimumClusterSize="3"
      ref="cluster"
      @click="clusteredMarkers($event)"
    >
      <gmap-custom-marker
        v-for="(m, index) in markers"
        :key="index"
        :id="index"
        :marker="m.position"
        ref="marker"
       >
        <v-avatar color="primary" size="25">
          <span
            @click="center = m.position"
            @mouseover="$emit('changeEl', index + 1)"
            @mouseleave="$emit('changeEl', '')"
            size="15"
            :class="
              hoveringEl - 1 === index ? 'white--text' : 'white--text'
            "
            >{{ index + 1 }}</span
          >
        </v-avatar>
      </gmap-custom-marker>
    </gmap-cluster>
</gmap-map>
</template>
```

My Script looks like this:

```
<script>
import GmapCustomMarker from 'vue2-gmap-custom-marker';
import GmapCluster from 'vue2-google-maps/dist/components/cluster';

export default {
  name: 'GoogleMap',

  components: {
    GmapCustomMarker,
    GmapCluster
  },

  props: {
    markers: {
      type: [Object, Array],
      required: false
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      center: {},
      places: [],
      currentPlace: null
    };
  },

  methods: {
    clusteredMarkers(event) {
      console.log(event.getMarkers());
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I had to remove sensitive information and left what I think is required to see the full scope of the issue. Please let me know if you need additional information.

On my console I get the right amount of markers when I click on the cluster but not sure how to identify them within my markers. Also I added an Id to the gmap-custom-marker and when I console.log(this.$refs.marker) I get access to that Id but not sure how to identify if is on the cluster or not. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem for gmap-marker - this is what worked for me, might be relevant to custom marker component too.

In method at `@click` event of cluster object - the handler method receives `Cluster` object, which contains function `getMarkers` that returns list of markers in some obscure format, rather than actual list of markers. But those markers have `getTitle` method, which pulls info that was set as `title` prop of `gmap-marker` component in the template. So, by setting some sort of id at that prop plus for each marker, it's possible to map cluster's "markers" to your markers.

Script example:

```
  toggleClusterInfo(cluster: Cluster) {
    //* Extract markers id list from cluster
    const markersIdList: string[] = []
    const gmapMarkers: { getTitle: () => string }[] = cluster.getMarkers()
    gmapMarkers.forEach((m) => markersIdList.push(m.getTitle()))

    // TODO: markersIdList contains list of values at `title` prop for each marker
    // use it to map to objects itself.
  }
```

And template example (important to set `title` prop to marker):

```
  <GmapCluster @click="toggleClusterInfo">
    <GmapMarker
      v-for="m in markers"
      :key="m.id"
      :title="m.id"
      :position="m.position"
      :clickable="true"
    ></GmapMarker>
  </GmapCluster>
```

Relevant info at this SO question:

[how to find the markers in the individual clusters in a  marker cluster object in google maps api v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271636/how-to-find-the-markers-in-the-individual-clusters-in-a-marker-cluster-object-i)